# Save loop results

Tags: matlab, loops, save

I have a simple question but I don't know how to solve it.

I want to process all the files in a folder and I want to write the output values on a separate line on a matrix. After direct the folder and get the list of the files and their names

```
filePattern=fullfile( myPath,'*.txt')
```

I applied a 'loop'. To save the results on each line for every file, this is what I'm doing but it doesn't work (the code works with one file, not with all of them).

```
text= {baseFileName, result2b, result3b, result4b, result5b};
```

Is there something wrong?

Thanks in advance! Greetings,

Emma

PD)

```
myPath = 'C:\SP\';
% if ~isdir(myPath)
%   errorMessage = sprintf('Error: The following folder does not exist:\n%s', myFolder);
%   uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
%   return;



    a= dir (fullfile(myPath,'*.DIM')); % 
    fileNames = { a.name };

 filePattern=fullfile( myPath,'*.txt');
 txtFiles= dir(filePattern);    
   for k = 1:length(txtFiles)
    baseFileName=txtFiles(k).name;
    fullFileName= fullfile(myPath,baseFileName);

fid=fopen(fullFileName, 'r+');
    for i = 1:18
    m{i} = fgetl(fid);
    end
     result2 = m{18};
     result2b= result2([12:19]);

(...)
```

**EDIT:**

I added a screenshoot about my variables. Is it possible because of the txtFiles is wrong?

[image]

Comment: You should add a tag which specify which is the programming language you use. Also you should show us the code you wrote and you said it's working.. we will try to improve it

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it's Matlab. I've added a piece of the code.

Comment: It is possible that happens because the result is in 'char' format? Or maybe it's because I've to do another "for/end"?

Comment: it is not possible to save a struct in a matrix.
You can either save it in another struct, or reformat the variable to something that you can save in a matrix.